# php mysql_insert_id() possible conflict with multi user

Tags: php, mysql-insert-id

We know that mysql_insert_id() will give the last inserted ID, but I am wondering if we could get a problem given the situation below.

---

**UserA** -> call a function that will insert a ROW to a TABLE and get the inserted ID

datetime of execution: **2013-10-01 10:18:25**

**ROW ID: 1**

---

**UserB** -> call a function that will insert a ROW to a TABLE and get the inserted ID

datetime of execution: **2013-10-01 10:18:26**

**ROW ID: 2**

---

Please notice that the time of execution is differ by only a second.

**Assume that UserB finished inserted the row before UserA executed mysql_insert_id()**

Does UserA will get the value of **ROW ID: 1** or **ROW ID: 2**

Answer (score 5):

No. `mysql_insert_id()` is also connection-safe, so for each user it will contain correct data since they will use different connections.

*Please, note, that using `mysql_` is bad idea since they are deprecated*

Answer (score 3):

Two users will have a different resource link to MySQL. PHP sort of does this for you by having the `$link_identifier` parameter as optional, but you should specify it.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Obligatory: don't use `mysql_*` functions, they are deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL connection. If the link identifier is not specified, the last link opened by mysql_connect() is assumed. If no such link is found, it will try to create one as if mysql_connect() was called with no arguments. If no connection is found or established, an E_WARNING level error is generated.